# React blank page after deployment to a sub directory

Tags: reactjs, deployment

I deploymed my finished react app to a sub directory on the server and I get a blank screen.

I did change the basename in my BrowserRouter:

```
<Provider store={store}><BrowserRouter basename="/bro2bro"><App/></BrowserRouter></Provider>
 , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

The change is working in my local enviournment with no problems and I see the basename url.
Just for testing, I deployed a dummy html/javascript website to the subdirectory and it worked. But when deploying (again just for testing) a simple react app with create-react-app to the subdirectory it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?
I did research this question and it seems like I have to change the basename which I already did. And I'm guessing it's not a problem with the server since the html/js website worked in the subdirectory.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You need to set the homepage property in your package.json file, see documentation: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths

Comment: Thanks a lot mate I just found out about it